# If statement getting Skipped in a Function

Tags: python

I have defined a function that takes three entries, 2 numbers and an array. The Array is a 800 row 10 col array.

The first column in the array has a number for a state (target_province)

What I want the function to do is go row by row and assign the column data for each province to an empty array and return it.

However it looks like the if statement is getting skipped. Did i use the wrong syntax?

```
def get_Province_Data(target_province,data,array):
    Date=[]
    Data_Set=[]
    f=0
    for rows in array:
        province=array[f][0]
        
        if province == target_province:
            
            np.append(Date,array[f][data]) 
            np.append(Data_Set,array[f][3]) #gets the date data from  rom f column 3
            print(1)
            
        f=f+1
        
    return Date,Data_Set

alpha, cases=get_Province_Data(35,4,CSV_Array)

print(cases)
'''
```

Comment: Try doing `print(f'{province=} {target_province=}')` to see if they actually are equal or not.

Comment: You mention that the province is specified as a number.  My wild guess is that you are comparing an actual number to a numeric string, which can never be true.

Comment: The province=array[f][0] is a string by default when you re reading from a file like '1', and parameter and target_province is an int like 1. So '1' == 1 is False.  You have to use province=int(array[f][0]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value read from files is String type by default. You are comparing lets say string '1' and int 1.

use this instead

```
if int(province) == target_province:
```

Comment: Thanks This worked! I didn't know that it read it as a string.  The print(1) statement that I put in the if statement printed when I did it.